# iOS 8 : MapKit's rotateEnabled toggling not working right away

Tags: swift, rotation, storyboard, mkmapview

In my application, I display a MKMapView which I have created using a storyboard. I have tried toggling the rotateEnabled boolean member of MKMapView, both via storyboard and programatically. It works, but only after some user interaction has occured. That is, the application will load the mapview and rotation will occur, until the user scrolls in any direction. At that point, the rotation will cease and the map locks into place. Is this behavior just an unpreventable part of the MKMapView class or can it be prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself by changing the MKMapView's tracking mode from

```
FollowWithHeading
```

to just

```
Follow
```